# Saving IPython HTML as PNG

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have an HTML code that I can display in the Jupyter notebook by using the following command:

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML

display(HTML(my_html_code))
```

However, I would like to save the output obtained from the code above as a PNG file, not only visualize it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
file = display(HTML(my_html_cde))
file.visualize(filename='content.png')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'visualize'

Comment: Didn't work with the following code:
file = display(HTML('<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3"><h1 style="text-align:center;font-size:14px">Header</h1></div>'))
file.visualize(filename='content.png')